# Getting this.props is not function when passes function to child React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I want to pass a function from parent (PendingRides) to child( ThirdSidebar)

But getting error **_this.props.onclk** is not a function.I have bind the function with this but still getting error.

```
class PendingRides extends React.Component {
          //Parent Class
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.switchclk=this.switchclk.bind(this);
    this.state={
        clk:false
    }
}


switchclk = (status)=>{

    console.log("Here2");
    this.setState({clk:status})

};

render(){


    return(

        <div>
            <ThirdSidebar onclk={this.switchclk}/>  // passing function to child

            {this.state.clk ?
                <div>
                <div className="layout-content">
                    <div className="layout-content-body">
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            :null}



        </div>

    )
}
```

}

```
class ThirdSidebar extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.showRides=this.showRides.bind(this);
    this.state={

    }
}

showRides = (e)=>{

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Here1");
    this.props.onclk(true)

};

render(){

    let hreflink=null;

    return(
        <div>
                <div className="layout-main"> {/*---------------------- sidebar ----------------------- */}
                    <div className="layout-sidebar">
                        <div className="layout-sidebar-backdrop">
                        </div>
                        <div className="layout-sidebar-body">
                            <div className="custom-scrollbar">
                                <nav id="sidenav" className="sidenav-collapse collapse">

                                            <ul className="sidenav-subnav">
                                                <li className="sidenav-subheading">Dashboards</li>
                                                <li onClick={(e)=>this.showRides(e)} className="active"><a href={hreflink}>Pending Rides</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div> {/* sidebar ends */}

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default ThirdSidebar

When the user clicks on pending rides it calls the function of showRides,where I am receiving props and getting error in child component

Comment: Once I fix the mismatched JSX in ThirdSidebar, the code works fine as-is: https://codesandbox.io/s/4xz4q1l9z4

Answer (score 1):

In your `PendingRides` component your `switchclk` function should be this,

```
switchclk(status){ //Remove arrow function

    console.log("Here2");
    this.setState({clk:status})

};
```

In your `ThirdSidebar` component your `showRides` function should be this,

```
showRides(e){ //Remove arrow function

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Here1");
    this.props.onclk(true)

};
```

Call above function like this,

```
<li onClick={this.showRides} className="active"><a href={hreflink}>Pending Rides</a></li>
```

**Note:** [How to use arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-dxf02?fontsize=14)

Comment: TypeError: this.props.onclk is not a function,

Comment: @MuhammadNabeel also check for JSX closing tag issues in ThirdSidebar component.

Answer (score 0):

If you use arrow function you don't need to bind your function anymore.
Actually, arrow function is an equivalent of `bind()`.

Remove your bind line:

```
this.showRides = this.showRides.bind(this); // to remove
```

Or change arrow function with:

```
showRides (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Here1");
    this.props.onclk(true)

};
```